# Why can't we write $\Delta S_{sys}=\frac{\Delta H_{sys}}{T}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If heat $q$ is transferred to the system, the heat transferred to the surroundings is $-q$. At constant pressure, $q = \Delta H_{sys}$  and also $-q = \Delta H_{surr}$.

It's common to see $\Delta S_{surr}= - \frac{\Delta H_{sys}}{T}$. So why can't we obtain a similar expression for  $\Delta S_{sys}$ as stated in the title?

Comment: Because the surroundings are always treated as an ideal constant temperature reservoir, with no entropy generation in the surroundings, so $\Delta S_{surr}=-Q_{sys}/T_{surr}$.  But, unless the change in the system is reversible, entropy will be generated within the system, and the entropy change of the system will not be $Q_{sys}/T_{surr}$

Comment: Thank you @ChetMiller, so as far as I understand it's because T is changing within the system? Why don't we just use something like $\Delta S_{system} = \frac{Q_{sys}}{T_{average-system}}$?

Comment: It's not just that T is changing within the system.  There is also entropy generation as a result of viscous dissipation of mechanical energy.  And there can be entropy generation as a result of chemical species diffusion..

Comment: Dear @ChetMiller, I think I now understand. For the system, $dS \geq \frac{dQ}{T}$ since we need to account for the change in entropy due to the change in heat in addition to whatever has been generated via the processes you outlined in your above comment. Whilst no entropy is generated in the surroundings so $dS =  \frac{-dQ}{T}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Basically correct.